# Convex Property Proof

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I just started learning about nonlinear optimization, and I'm having trouble understanding concepts of convex. Could anyone help me write and understand the proof of the below statement? Thank you!

Let    $g :P  →  \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on a convex domain $P⊆\mathbb{R}^n$.
Show that g is convex if and only if
$$ (a-b)^T (∇g(a)−∇g(b)) \ge 0, \quad ∀ a,b ∈ P $$

Comment: That's a name for this property, by the way: the gradient of $g$ is "monotone". This theorem is a generalization of the fact that if $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is convex and differentiable then $g'$ is non-decreasing.